# How do I install mod-jk in linux?

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, mod-jk, suse

I need to run tomcat behind apache - am running suse 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way of installing mod-jk is using yast.  Alternatively the command:
sudo /sbin/yast --install apache2-mod_jk.  With this command you will need your installation media to be present.